# Link for SQL MI as DR

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

Can i use preview feature link for SQL MI as DR site (database) for on-prem SQL Server instance?.We don't want to use the SQL MI for reporting purpose. If the answer is yes, if i failover to SQL MI database as primary in case of DR, when original primary onprem SQLDB comes up, can i failback from SQL MI??

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/managed-instance-link-feature-overview?view=azuresql

Nothing. Looking for an conceptual understanding.

Comment: Any update on this please?. Appreciate replies..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to failback to on-prem is only available in SQL 2022. See [The Ultimate Freedom of Movement between SQL Server 2022 and Managed Instance - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/the-ultimate-freedom-of-movement-between-sql-server-2022-and/ba-p/3677225)

Please let us know if you have further queries.